# Navigate using LongListSelector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listboxitem, longlistselector, panorama-control

I have a LongListSelector and have wrapped the data with a listBox so that I can use the Tilt Effect on the items. I was wondering how I navigate to different pages from clicking on each item.

I am using a Panorama view, there are 5 different items, if that makes sense. I have never used one before, so you might need to speak in layman's terms please.

Answer (score 0):

You can have buttons within the LongListSelector. Each button represents one page of the panorama item. Then you can navigate to the panorama page by selecting the panorama index.

```
(pan.Items[curIndex] as PanoramaItem).Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
pan.SetValue(Panorama.SelectedItemProperty, pan.Items[(curIndex + 1) % pan.Items.Count]); 
pan.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)); (pan.Items[curIndex] as 
PanoramaItem).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Check out this link for more info. 
http://xme.im/slide-or-change-panorama-selected-item-programatically#sthash.wyPDtWil.dpuf

The above code navigates to the next page. To navigate to a specific page simple change the "curIndex + 1" in the second line to the index of the page you want. With 5 pages your index range should be 0-4.

Comment: Not sure if you misunderstood my question. I am starting on the panorama page, I have 3 columns. The first is a normal list box, the second is a LongListSelector. I have 5 items in my long list selector. I have just added a tilt effect to the LLS so now I want to go to a pivot page when I click one of the items, but I'm struggling to find out how to do this, because normally you can just double click the item and it creates an event handler and you put "NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/nextPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsoilute". I don't know how to do this for that, using the sampledata?

Comment: because obviously each item is going to go to a separate pivot page.

Comment: I'm not sure I still understand. It is because you want an event handler for each item, that I propose a button. This will allow for the Click event to be used to initiate the navigation. Secondly NavigationService cannot be used to navigate panorama "pages" as they aren't actually separate pages but simply parts of one panorama page and that is why I suggested using this panorama selection function.